# Lesti_FPC on Magento 1.4

Tags: full-page-cache

Anyone tried using [Lesti_FPC](https://github.com/GordonLesti/Lesti_Fpc) with Magento 1.4? 
Worked? Challanges?

On Gordon's website says:
`Lesti_Fpc is compatible with Magento CE 1.5, 1.6, 1.6.1, 1.6.2.0, 1.7, 1.8, 1.8.1, 1.9`

Comment: You know that you want to upgrade the shop, because a lot of security issues are fixed in later version. Beside this I would try to run the unit tests for a first impression

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because 3rd party module. Even though it is extremely popular, you are asking about specific compatibility that should be asked to the module creator.

Comment: works fine on 1.4. Forgot about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments listed at this page:
http://gordonlesti.com/lestifpc/comment-page-1/

It should work fine with Magento 1.4.

Do make sure to take backups before you install it just in case if you need to roll back.

Besides that, I agree with Fabian that Magento 1.4 is just too old and it is highly recommended that you start planning your upgrade paths.